# Precompiled build with asset output files excluded from source control not moving output files to the precompiled build folder

Tags: orchardcms

I am having an issue with asset output files not being copied to the precompiled build folder when doing a precompiled build. I am trying to keep the output files out of the project and source control and have our build server/script compile them on the fly to prevent inconsistent/stale output files as mentioned in the documentation http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Processing-client-side-assets/#excluding-output-files-from-source-control.

I have all the Assets.json files in my custom modules/theme setup to input files from Assets folders and output them to their respective Styles/Scripts folders. The build script runs a nuget restore -> `npm install` -> `gulp build`-> `build Precompiled` and then archives and deploys what is in the precompiled build folder.

The problem is that the compiled asset files never make it to the precompiled build folder so they are never archived and deployed. If I look on the build server in the src folder I see that the gulp build did work and put the compiled assets files in their respective Styles/Scripts folders, they just never got moved. What do I need to do to get them to move to the precompiled build folder? Is this a supported scenario out of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out on gitter, what we do is include the compiled assets in the csproj (them not being in the csproj is what is causing them not to be copied to the precompiled output) but ignore those folders with some wildcard rules via git ignore, so the compiled assets never get commited to source control.